# how change url when use $.ajax and title and

Tags: php, jquery

i use this code cuz i dont want my header or my footer bar load in every page

```
$('a#load').click(function(autoload){
    autoload.preventDefault();
    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    var base = $(this).attr('base');
    var id = $(this).attr('more-data');

    if(base === 'basic'){
        $.ajax({
            url: location,
            data: {  },
            success: function(result) {
             $("#content").html(result);
            }
        });
    }//if base
});
```

but how i can change URL in address bar for seo?  and how change title of that page?  or/and keywords  ?
its possible?
its must be cuz in facebook we see ajax load without load header and chat bar in footer
and if facebook use another method please give me a example how use ajax load for best SEO - speed
thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Stuff you do in JavaScript generally doesn't do anything for you SEO-wise. Facebook loads content via AJAX to speed things up for users browsing around the site, but there's plain-old-static-HTML loadable versions of those URLs too - that's what Google indexes.
2. Facebook et. al. do this with the HTML5 history/state APIs. There's a ready-made library called [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) that's handy for this.

Comment: can you give me example how its work? thank you

Comment: Follow the link and see the examples there.